# MySQL: can't returning a POINT type using WHERE clause

Tags: php, mysql, geospatial, spatial, mysql-spatial

i have some points stored in a MySQL database, they are stored as POINT types with an x and y value. I am trying to search and return specific points using the x and y values in a WHERE clause.

heres an example of a query i am trying to get working:

```
"SELECT id, x(coords) AS lng, y(coords) AS lat
 FROM my_points
 WHERE x(coords) = $lng AND y(coords) = $lat"
```

but this does not work. I dont have experience with the MySQL spatial types, any help would be appreciated!

a comment from below that gives some more info:

i should have mentioned that im actually using a PHP frameworks ORM for the DB queries, the SQL i've written above is just suppose to represent what i was trying to achieve using the ORM's syntax. I dont think the problem is with the ORM though as i've used other functions in the 'WHERE' clauses before. Im just not too sure if its correct to use ' x() = lng AND y() = lat ' in a 'WHERE' clause. With the normal correct SQL syntax, you using x() AND y() in the WHERE clause give me what i'm looking for?

Comment: You're missing a "from clause"

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Answer (score 0):

If your columns names really have parentheses in them you need to back tick them:

```
SELECT `id`, `x(coords)` AS `lng`, `y(coords)` AS `lat`
FROM `my_points`
WHERE `x(coords)` = $lng AND `y(coords)` = $lat
```

All un-quoted column and table names can consist of any alphanumeric characters in the server's default character set, plus the characters '_' and '$'. Names can start with any character that is legal in a name, including a digit.

Column and table names be be in back ticks, which allows use of any character *except* backtick, ASCII 0, and ASCII 255. This is useful when a name contains special characters or is a reserved word.

There are two additional limits for database and table names, even if you back tick them. First, you cannot use the '.' character because it is the separator in database_name.table_name and database_name.table_name.col_name notation. Second, you cannot use the UNIX or Windows pathname separator  ('/' or '\').

Comment: i should have mentioned that im actually using a PHP frameworks ORM for the DB queries, the SQL i've written above is just suppose to represent what i was trying to achieve using the ORM's syntax. I dont think the problem is with the ORM though as i've used other functions in the 'WHERE' clauses before. Im just not too sure if its correct to use ' x() = lng AND y() = lat ' in a 'WHERE' clause. With the normal correct SQL syntax, you using x() AND y() in the WHERE clause give me what i'm looking for?

Comment: If you already know the coordinates why are you querying for them? Have you tried the query @ThriceGood? Is it returning an error?